# pass multiple content from layout to page

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I would like to know if there is a way to pass a dynamic named content to the page from the layout.

For example,

Layout

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        {{ content }}
    </div>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; Company 2015</p>
    </footer>
    <script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
    {{ page.other_content }}<!-- Objective: To write scripts that varies with page -->
</body>
```

Page

```
--- 
layout: default
title: About Us Page
---

<p> This is about us page </p>

{% capture other_content %}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log("About us page.");
    });
</script>
{% endcapture %}
```

Is there a way to render multiple content sections in pages from layout?

---

In ASP.NET we can do this is the Layout page.

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

In content page we can render that section like this.

```
@section scripts {
    Hey I'm actually on the _Main layout. 
    I can vary according to the page.
    My presence is not mandatory in every page
}
```

Can this be done with jekyll?

Comment: Your approach with  `capture` is ok.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GitHub Pages disallow plugins, so I'll stick to vanilla Jekyll workarounds. You can of course use plugins, generate your site locally and host the results on GitHub.

---

This is ugly, but possible. Keep your layout as is:

```
<body>
  <!-- varies with page -->
  {{ page.other_content }}
</body>
```

Then in your page file, define the property `other_content` in the front matter:

```
---
other_content: |
  <script>
    console.log("You can't stop me!");
  </script>
---
```

The pipe character [denotes a multiline string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/in-yaml-how-do-i-break-a-string-over-multiple-lines). Per YAML's rules, your scripts must be indented by spaces ([no tabs allowed](http://yaml.org/faq.html)).

---

If your scripts become too large, you can move them to separate files, and the front matter of your pages would refer to the script file names instead:

```
---
scripts: [test]
---
```

In the layout:

```
{% for s in page.scripts %}
<script src="{{ s }}.js"></script>
{% endfor %}
```

This works if test.js is in the same directory as the page using it. You can use [`site.baseurl`](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/#project-page-url-structure) to get absolute paths, etc.